# Sql - Grouping tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query;

```
    SELECT Name, MAX(A) AS A, MAX(B) AS B
    FROM (
    SELECT l.Name, SUM(A.Count) AS A, 0 AS B
    FROM List l
    LEFT JOIN A ON A.Name = l.Name
    GROUP BY l.Name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l.Name, 0 AS A, SUM(B.Count)AS B
    FROM List l
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.Name = l.Name
    GROUP BY l.Name) sub
    GROUP BY Name
    ORDER BY Name
```

My tables and query result is here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/11

And I need grouping Table-A with Table-C on C.createDate(ex;2017-2018-2019)

Each year -> add Column

C_ID in table A -> ID in table C

2017 -> ID: 3,5

2018 -> ID: 2,6,8

2019 -> ID: 1,4,7

Example : For Product 1 (Only Table A Values)

2017 -> 13 ; 2018 -> 23+11 = 34 ; 2019 -> 5 ; B -> 8+10=18 (8 in 2018 , 10 in 2017 but year is not important for Table B)

My Target Results For Example ;

```
    Name     |  2017  |  2018  |  2019  |  B  
    ---------+--------+--------+--------+------
    Product1 |   13   |   34   |   5    |  18
    Product2 |   21   |   0    |   3    |  0
    Product3 |   13   |   0    |   7    |  15
    Product4 |   18   |   27   |   0    |  29
    Product5 |   0    |   8    |   25   |  32
    Product6 |   0    |   0    |   0    |  0
    Product7 |   22   |   14   |   0    |  0
    Product8 |   0    |   26   |   4    |  23
    Product9 |   0    |   11   |   0    |  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the same way as Thorsten Kettner answer. But i think you have to use `CASE` and sum of `A.COUNT`. You can use `YEAR()` to extract year from date and then `SUM` using `case` statement for respective year.

```
SELECT List.NAME,IFNULL(MYAC.2017,0) AS '2017', IFNULL(MYAC.2018,0) AS '2018', IFNULL(MYAC.2019,0) AS '2019',IFNULL(BSUM.TOTAL,0) as B
FROM
(
  SELECT
    A.NAME,
    SUM(case when YEAR(C.CREATEDATE) = 2017 then A.Count else 0 end) as '2017',
    SUM(case when YEAR(C.CREATEDATE) = 2018 then A.Count else 0 end) AS '2018',
    SUM(case when YEAR(C.CREATEDATE) = 2019 then A.Count else 0 end) AS '2019'
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = A.C_ID
  GROUP BY A.NAME
) MYAC
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT NAME,SUM(B.COUNT) AS TOTAL
  FROM B
  GROUP BY NAME
) BSUM ON BSUM.NAME = MYAC.NAME
RIGHT JOIN
List on List.Name = MYAC.NAME
ORDER BY List.NAME;
```

[**CHECK OUTPUT FIDDLE HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=815b659cd659b17f351dbce4074cfeef)

**Update** You can use the answer with `LEFT JOIN`below also as `RIGHT JOIN` often affects the readability.

```
SELECT List.Name,IFNULL(MYABC.2017,0) AS '2017', IFNULL(MYABC.2018,0) AS '2018', IFNULL(MYABC.2019,0) AS '2019',IFNULL(MYABC.B,0) as B from List
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MYAC.Name,MYAC.2017 AS '2017', MYAC.2018 AS '2018', MYAC.2019 AS '2019',BSUM.TOTAL as B
FROM
(
  SELECT
    A.NAME,
    SUM(case when YEAR(C.CREATEDATE) = 2017 then A.Count else 0 end) as '2017',
    SUM(case when YEAR(C.CREATEDATE) = 2018 then A.Count else 0 end) AS '2018',
    SUM(case when YEAR(C.CREATEDATE) = 2019 then A.Count else 0 end) AS '2019'
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = A.C_ID
  GROUP BY A.NAME
) MYAC
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT NAME,SUM(B.COUNT) AS TOTAL
  FROM B
  GROUP BY NAME
) BSUM ON BSUM.NAME = MYAC.NAME ) MYABC
on List.name = MYABC.name
ORDER BY List.NAME;
```

[**CHECK OUTPUT FIDDLE WITH LEFT JOIN HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f49052a496158459d43b1a417f72da7b)

Comment: Product6 isn't in result.

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN , I have added one more join with `List` to get your expected result. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Ah, the figures are sums of the count field. I missed that. Well spotted. I would never right outer join, however, for I often find right joins hard to read. Just select from list and left outer join the two subqueries.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, True!  `Right Joins` affects the readability. I will update the answer with `Left join`. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on your question. For the answer, search for `[YourDB]` and change it to yours database's name.
In the answer, a left join is initially performed to bring the `YEAR` from table C. After that, a summarisation on the view T is performed and T1 view is created. After the summerisation, a pivoting is performed on T1 view to get the PIV view with the years as columns. Lastly, a join with table B is performed to bring the SUM of column B.

```
-- Need to bring the information from PIV and B
SELECT [PIV].[Name], "2017", "2018", "2019", [B].[Count_B]
FROM
(
-- This subquery takes the output from view T to create a summarization on both the product and year.
SELECT [T].[Name], SUM([T].[Count]) AS My_Sum, [T].[My_year]
FROM
(
--This subquery creates the view T which brings only the year from table C. The year is important to have for the final output to create the columns.
SELECT [Name]
      ,[Count]
      ,[C_ID]
      ,YEAR([YourDB].[dbo].[C].[createDate]) as My_year
  FROM [YourDB].[dbo].[A]
  LEFT JOIN [YourDB].[dbo].[C]
  ON [C_ID]=ID) AS T
  GROUP BY [T].[Name], [T].[My_year]) AS T1
  PIVOT
  (
  MAX([T1].My_Sum)
  FOR My_year IN ("2017", "2018", "2019")
  )PIV
  LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT [Name],SUM([Count]) AS Count_B
  FROM [YourDB].[dbo].[B]
  GROUP BY [Name])B
  ON [PIV].[Name] = [B].[Name]
```